# How to debug Access Violation that it thrown from windows library ucrtbase?

Tags: python, c, windows, winapi, windbg

My app (java based) launches python for Windows, which, in turn, calls `os.spawnv` to launch another python.

From time to time I am having Access Violation exception.

```
00 005eedb0 763e68f3 ucrtbase!<lambda_7d9ee38b11181ddfdf5bd66394e53cb7>::operator()+0x1b
01 005eedfc 763e65d9 ucrtbase!construct_environment_block<char>+0xdb
02 005eee14 763e7aba ucrtbase!common_pack_argv_and_envp<char>+0x31
03 005eeebc 763e778a ucrtbase!execute_command<char>+0x62
04 005eeee8 763e8066 ucrtbase!common_spawnv<char>+0x13f
05 005eeef8 65a323d7 ucrtbase!_spawnve+0x16
06 005eef38 65a360c6 python35!os_spawnve_impl(int mode = 0n0, struct _object * path = 0x03adfde0, struct _object * argv = 0x03b258a0, struct _object * env = 0x03b25a80)+0x1a7 [c:\build\cpython\modules\posixmodule.c @ 5299]
```

I've set bp on `c:\build\cpython\modules\posixmodule.c @ 5299` and here is what I see in python sources

```
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
spawnval = _spawnve(mode, path_char, argvlist, envlist);
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

I've checked all arguments twice: they are ok. `mode` is 0, `path_char` is path to my interpeter, `argvlist` and `envlist` are both  `char**`: NULL-terminated arrays of NULL-teminated strings.

So, it is not python fault.

I know that `_spawnve` is not thread safe, but there is only one thread.

I do not have sources nor private symbols for MS ucrtbase. What is the right approach to investigate it?

--

What is the difference between `ucrtbased.dll` and `ucrtbase.dll`? 
Should I compile Python against ucrtbased.dll to find more symbols?

Comment: A debug build uses ucrtbased.dll and python35_d.dll. Using a debug build should make it easier to find the problem. Try `!analyze -v`.

Comment: You should have the source for the CRT installed with Visual Studio 2015. For example, I see the definition of `construct_environment_block` in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\exec\cenvarg.cpp".

Comment: Crt sources and private do come in sdk / wdk under src folder in the vc dir tree

Comment: Debug bld = unoptimsed code src line numbers match disassembly no function chunking no dead code eliminstion no unused function elimination no inlining it is the best possible match between src and symbols

Comment: @blabb, the latest CRT sources have moved to the "Windows Kits" folder; they're no longer in the VC directory. They're installed with Visual Studio VC++ (2015 for Python 3.5), not the SDK as far as I know.

Comment: Expanding on @eryksun's comment, the reason why the CRT sources have moved from the compiler to the Windows SDK is, because the Universal CRT is part of the OS now.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Mystery solved.

See https://bugs.jython.org/issue29908 for details, but basically `spawnve()` is broken. It relies on these secret current directory environment variables that start with an `=`, and is likely to crash if the environment doesn't contain them.

`cmd.exe` and `explorer.exe` set them when launching processes, but if you launch a process yourself with a constrained environment that doesn't include them, then that process itself tries to call `spawnve()` you are heading to crash land.

The workaround is to set at least one environment variable that matches the pattern; e.g. `=c:=pants` and you are good.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same problem while trying to build SciPy; an access violation is thrown as part of setup.py trying to `spawnve()` a C compiler.

I haven't gotten to the bottom of it yet, but stepping through the disassembly, in my case at least. Here's what happens:

- Calls `get_environment_from_os()` which gives you a pointer to the current process's environment variables.
- Iterates through this list of null-terminated strings looking  for environment variables whose name starts with an '`=`'
- Apparently this is Windows's way of expressing the set of current directories, e.g. there should be an environment variable '`=c:`' with a value like "`c:\mystuff`"
- It never finds any, and trundling off into uninitialized memory in its futile quest.
- Boom.

Inspecting the memory address returned by `get_environment_from_os()` shows me a pretty sane looking list of environment variables, but none whose key begins with an '`=`' character.

I'm still digging into exactly why and how things get into this state; it doesn't always seem to happen which makes me suspect threads, but like you, I can't find any evidence to back this up; though I don't have intimate knowledge about how `distutils` works.